# Water not circulating through baseboards

Tags: hvac, heating, baseboard

2 zone (1 radiant floor, 1 baseboards) hot water heating system. Radiant floor (t’d off main feed) seems to be working fine. None of the baseboard loops are hot, and the pipe was hot before the circulator pump but not. Plumber comes out today, says circulator is drawing close to double normal amperage, says the pump is shot (which seems reasonable, given that’s also where pipe gets cool). Plumber can’t get back here until Monday. I buy and install new circulator, pretty straight forward. Turn the system back on, hear the circulator running, but pipes stay super cold. Run the pump for a solid 30 minutes, at which point is start making some odd noises. Crack the seal to make sure there’s water flowing through, it’s definitely wet. However now the pipes are cold before the circulator as well, with the biggest drop in temperature now at the low water cut off probe halfway up the wall. I’m at a loss and don’t believe my plumber diagnosed this right. Help! Thanks in advance...[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Usual problem (particularly after swapping the pump) is air in the pipes/system. Find the bleeders and use them. Unusual problem would be having part of the loop freeze.

Comment: Turns out the problem was the flo-chek just past the circulator. I manually opened it via the top thumb-screw and hot water started flowing. Do I even need a flo-check with this model of circulator?